# How can I force my phonegap app to use the wifi instead of cellular data?

Tags: cordova

Here is my scenario...I have a PhoneGap app that needs to be connected to a wireless router to work.  The loading screen instructs the user to connect to the wifi and then keeps checking for a url (from the router) to load.  Here's the problem...

1. I launch the app.
2. I connect to the wifi.
3. The $http get request continues to receive a 404 error.
4. If I disabled 4G data then it suddenly switches to wifi and works.

So, my question is...is there a way (in phonegap, preferably without a plugin) to force my $http get request to use the wifi instead of the network connection that was active when the app launched?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt without using any plugin, you can do this. As you can check which type of connection you app is using in phonegap & take actions depending on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the type of connection via cordova, but you can check by yourself and handle it manually. Have you thought about a funcion like this:

```
function checkConnection () {
 if (navigator.connection.type === "WiFi" ) {
      return true;
} else {
     return false:
}

}
```

And call it before all your ajax.

Or maybe a listener to lock your app when the user is disconnected from the WiFi